# Python C tuple

Tags: python, c

Пояснения к скрипту. Есть связка freeradius+python, нужно воспользоваться модулем sqlalchemy результат я получил list преобразовал его в tuple вернул в функцию, но freeradius жалуется на ошибку, если тот же самый результат подставить в ручную то результат положительный. Проблема в функции authorize. Какие могут быть варианты, почему Си не хочет воспринимать тип данных tuple, я уверен на 100% что переменная получена верна.

```
import re
import radiusd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

dbHandle = None
pattern_ip = '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}$'

def log(level, s):
    radiusd.radlog(level, 'pyradius.py: ' + s)

def instantiate(p):
    global dbHandle
    p = p
    engine = create_engine('mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/db', pool_size=64, max_overflow=0)
    dbHandle = engine.connect()

def profiles(profile):
    sql = """SELECT {0}""".format(profile)
    return tuple(dbHandle.execute(sql).fetchall())

def usernames(ip):
    sql = """SELECT {0}""".format(ip)
    result = tuple(dbHandle.execute(sql).fetchone())
    if not result:
        log(radiusd.L_INFO, 'user reject: ' + ip)
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_REJECT

    sql = """SELECT {0}""".format(ip)
    log(radiusd.L_DBG, 'select attribites')
    attr = tuple(dbHandle.execute(sql).fetchall())
            """передаю нужный результат в функцию authorize"""
    return attr

def authorize(p):
    user = p[0][1][1:-1]
    pat = re.compile(pattern_ip)
    if pat.search(user):
        g = usernames(user)
        if g:
                            """получаю результат от функции usernames:
                            (('Framed-IP-Address', '10.10.10.1'), 
                            ('Framed-IP-Netmask', '255.255.255.255'), 
                            ('Cisco-Account-Info', 'AUNL_10M_DAY'), 
                            ('Cisco-Account-Info', 'ALOCAL'), 
                            ('Cisco-Account-Info', 'AUNL_20M_NIGHT'), 
                            ('Idle-Timeout', '86400'))
                            freeradius не хочет кушать полученные переменные, если в ручную
                            подставить то все проходит на отлично."""
            return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_UPDATED, g, (('Auth-Type', 'python'),))
        else:
            return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_REJECT)
    else:
        g2 = profiles(user)
        if g2:
            return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_UPDATED, g2, (('Auth-Type', 'python'),))
        else:
            return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_REJECT)
```

Ошибки от freeradius:

```
Error: rlm_python:authorize: tuple element 0 is not a tuple
Error: rlm_python:authorize: tuple element 1 is not a tuple
Error: rlm_python:authorize: tuple element 2 is not a tuple
Error: rlm_python:authorize: tuple element 3 is not a tuple
Error: rlm_python:authorize: tuple element 4 is not a tuple
Error: rlm_python:authorize: tuple element 5 is not a tuple
```

Код из rlm_python.c:

```
 {
    int             i;
    int             tuplesize;
    VALUE_PAIR      *vp;

    /*
 *  If the Python function gave us None for the tuple,
 *  then just return.
 */
    if (pValue == Py_None)
            return;

    if (!PyTuple_CheckExact(pValue)) {
            radlog(L_ERR, "rlm_python:%s: non-tuple passed", funcname);
            return;
    }
    /* Get the tuple tuplesize. */
    tuplesize = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(pValue);
    for (i = 0; i < tuplesize; i++) {
            PyObject *pTupleElement = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(pValue, i);
            PyObject *pStr1;
            PyObject *pStr2;
            int pairsize;
            const char *s1;
            const char *s2;

            if (!PyTuple_CheckExact(pTupleElement)) {
                    radlog(L_ERR, "rlm_python:%s: tuple element %d is not a tuple", funcname, i);
                    continue;
            }
            /* Check if it's a pair */
            if ((pairsize = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(pTupleElement)) != 2) {
                    radlog(L_ERR, "rlm_python:%s: tuple element %d is a tuple of size %d. Must be 2", funcname, i, pairsize);
                    continue;
            }
            pStr1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(pTupleElement, 0);
            pStr2 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(pTupleElement, 1);
            if ((!PyString_CheckExact(pStr1)) || (!PyString_CheckExact(pStr2))) {
                    radlog(L_ERR, "rlm_python:%s: tuple element %d must be as (str, str)", funcname, i);
                    continue;
            }
            s1 = PyString_AsString(pStr1);
            s2 = PyString_AsString(pStr2);
            /* xxx Might need to support other T_OP */
            vp = pairmake(s1, s2, T_OP_EQ);
            if (vp != NULL) {
                    pairadd(vpp, vp);
                    radlog(L_DBG, "rlm_python:%s: '%s' = '%s'", funcname, s1, s2);
            } else {
                    radlog(L_DBG, "rlm_python:%s: Failed: '%s' = '%s'", funcname, s1, s2);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну ругается этот rlm_python на то, что элементы tuple сами не являются tuple. А что получается из объекта, полученного от fetch_on после применения функции tuple, я не знаю, но сомневаюсь, что это tuple of tuples of strings. Возможно это tuple of lists?

Comment: Внутри tuple элементы не являлись tuple, а были <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.RowProxy'>. Преобразовал в tuple и все пошло. Спасибо!

Comment: alexlz, оформите как ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел в неотвеченных